# Reference request: some properties of Dedekind rings

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, galois-theory, dedekind-domain

I'm looking for a source where I can look up for the proofs of certain fancy statements regarding Galois extensions of fraction fields of Dedekind rings. That is let $R$ be a Dedekind ring with fraction field $F=Frac(R)$ and $F \subset E$ a finite Galois extension and $A$ integral closure of $R$ in $E$.

The statements I'm looking for are:

1) $A$ is also Dedekind ring

2) $A$ is finite $R$ module and flat

3) there exist a $f \in R$ such that the localization $R[f] \subset A[f]$ is etale

I know proofs for 1) and 2) if we everywhere replace "Dedekind" by discrete valuation ring. Can it reduced to this case? ie if we can show that for all primes $\frak{p} \subset $ $R$ after localizations 1) and 2) holds for $R_{\frak{p}} \subset A_{\frak{p}}$ then it also holds for $R \subset A$. Does this strategy make sense?

Comment: For 1) the idea is that the prime ideals $P_j\subset A$ above $p\subset R$ become principal in $(R-p)^{-1} A$ because they correspond to the extensions of the discrete valuation of $(R-p)^{-1} R$. Since $p$ is inversible then $P_j=(\pi_{P_j},p)$ is inversible. For 3) by the primitive element theorem $E=F(a)\cong F[x]/(g(x))$ with $g\in R[x]_{monic}$ and with $d=Disc(g)$ then $A[d^{-1}]/R[d^{-1}]$ is etale (it is immediate that its prime ideals are the $(p,g_j(a))$ where $d\not \in p$ and $g_j$ is an irreducible factor of $g\in R/p[x]$ and $p=\prod_j (p,g_j(a))$)

Comment: $A=R[a,\cup \pi_p,b_{P_j,i}]$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, where $\pi_{P_j}$ are uniformizers of the finitely many $P_j \ni d$ and $b_{P_j,i}\bmod P_j$ are generators of $(A/P_j) / (R/p)$.

Comment: @reuns: Thank you for the answer. ok, so you use for 1) a characterization of Dedekind domains that says $A$ DD iff every fractional ideal is invertible (compare with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_ideal#Dedekind_domains). The only aspect  that seems not clear to me is that you have only showed that every prime ideal is inverible. (simply by $I:= \pi_{P_j}^{-1},p^{-1}$ since $p$ principal) Does this immerdiately imply that *every* ideal is invertible?

Comment: and on 3): I not fully understood your argument on etaleness of $A[d^{-1}]/R[d^{-1}]$. Which etaleness criterion are you using here?

Comment: Finite integral extension everywhere unramified